# collecting and organizing rosbag files

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recording rosbag files is great. After multiple recording sessions, I'm left with all these bag files that are really only telling me date/time by direct observation. I can do rosbag info to get more details. I was wondering if anyone had a best practice for collecting, storing, and organizing rosbag files. I'm thinking of a database containing rosbag files with additional metadata including some text field for a description of what was recorded.

Maybe this problem has already been solved.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218678/collecting-and-organizing-rosbag-files/) by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two (commercial) alternatives (I've no connections with either):

- Marv Robotics, by [Ternaris](https://ternaris.com/marv-robotics/) (also [presented at ROSCon16](http://roscon.ros.org/2016/presentations/MARVRoboticsPangercic.pdf) ([video](https://vimeo.com/187705380)))
- BotBags: [Announcing BotBags, the cloud rosbag storage service](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-botbags-the-cloud-rosbag-storage-service/916)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2019-11-11**:
It looks like BotBags no longer exists, but maybe https://github.com/cruise-automation/webviz is suitable (not sure if it plays back bag files that are local or online)?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[bag-database](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-users/2016-May/069991.html) takes care of many aspects you asked about.
There may not be publicly accessible running instance as of today, so you may have to run one by yourself.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1